# Toggle button resets on scroll listview with CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

Good day, I tried all possible solution but ain't work for me. My problem is my toggle button changed itself when i scrolled down and scrolled up.

> **gold star toggle button is check:**

[image]

> **scrolling down:**

[image]

> **scrolling up and the star change itself to white star**

[image]

**MyCursorAdapter.java**

```
class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        Context context;
        Database db;
        int f;
        public ClientCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
            super(context, c, flags);
            this.context = context;
            db = new Database(context);
        }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,viewGroup,false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(final View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        final TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.Title);
        final TextView artist = view.findViewById(R.id.Artist);
        ToggleButton music = view.findViewById(R.id.minus_one);
        ToggleButton favorite = view.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
        f = (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        music.setEnabled(false);
        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("AUDIOFILE")) != null) {
            music.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            music.setChecked(false);
        }
        int ft = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("FAVORITE"));
        if (ft == 1) {
            favorite.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            favorite.setChecked(false);
        }
        title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TITLE")));
        artist.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ARTIST")));

        favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if (b) {
                    db.update_favorite(b,title.getText().toString(),artist.getText().toString());
                    compoundButton.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    db.update_favorite(b,title.getText().toString(),artist.getText().toString());
                    compoundButton.setChecked(false);
                }

            }
        });

    }


}
```

I don't know whats going on here. I'm new in android. please help.

Comment: Try to use a recyclerview.It will solve the issue.

Comment: ok. I'll try :-)

Comment: @SibinDavis thank for your suggestion and that's help me a lot but now I facing another problem.. when my first item toggle button is check, the other  items from first item are automatically check itself. i mean when I check the first item, the 11 position is automatically check itself and 22 position automatically itself and soon...

Comment: what you mean by checking?

Comment: What I mean is when I turn on(set to true) the toggle button and scroll down, the other toggle button turn on automatically

Comment: Can you show your adapter?

Comment: thanks for your help, I figured out by myself,. I override the getItemViewType to my Recycler Adapter and now its work. :-)